Added .lowercase-alpha-list now my list is adding an extra period
I have added this code to the additional css:
.lowercase-alpha-list {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}

.lowercase-alpha-list li::after {
    content: none;
}

Here is how I implemented the HTML:
<ol class="lowercase-alpha-list">
<li>“Attendee/s” means: an individual other than the Authorized User or an entity that Customer has authorized and/or invited to access the Platform as a participant or guest; or an individual whose Personal Data was added to the Platform by the Authorized Users or at Customer's request by Meetaverse.</li>
<li>“Affiliate” means an entity that is either controlling, controlled by, or under a common control with the subject matter entity whereby “control” shall mean the direct or indirect holding of more than 50% of equity ownership or voting rights.</li>
<li>“Authorized User/s” means an individual who is an identified representative of Customer to whom Customer assigns the right to manage and use the Platform for and on behalf of Customer.</li>
<li>“Customer Personal Data” means Personal Data of Customer's Authorized Users and Attendees.</li>
<li>“Data Protection Laws” means all applicable data privacy, data protection, and cybersecurity laws, rules, regulations, and guidelines issued by authorized public authorities to which the Customer Personal Data are subject. “Data Protection Laws” shall include but not be limited to US Data Protection Laws, the EU General Data Protection Regulation 2016/679 (“GDPR”), and Data Protection Act 2018 (“UK GDPR”).</li>
<li>“IDTA” and “Addendum” means international data transfer agreement and international data transfer addendum respectively issued under section 119A of the UK GDPR effective as of 21 March 2022 as amended and updated from time to time.</li>



content: ''; is the correct method, try that.

After implementing this, problem still exists.

Try changing the list-style-type and see what that does.  This is a strange one because something is adding those periods... ...is there a :before being applied somewhere in the lists?  Because that period shows up before the <li>.

Drop a URL if it's live and I'll take a look.

Thank you for this:
https://meetaverse.com/4474-2/
I feel like it may be in the theme. Possibly in the #onetrust

So, the theme is adding it as a :before but it's not a character or 'content', instead it's using a height and width value and then a background colour:
.text-entry li:before{
    background-color: transparent;
}

That ought to do the trick.
You could even go with the nuclear option:
.text-entry li:before{
     display: none;
}

Or... ...a more comprehensive version of the first rule:
.text-entry li:before{
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

Just make sure this CSS loads after the theme's CSS.
What I would recommend however, because the theme obviously has that rule in there for a reason, is that you try and use your class that is on the <ol> element to make the rule more specific, so that you only apply this effect to this particular list.
So maybe like:
.text-entry .lowercase-alpha-list li:before{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}


The last solution worked. Thank you so much!

Very welcome. Best of luck with the rest of the site.  :-)
